# Определение местонахождение маркера на руке по фотографии Java

Tags: java, изображения, opencv, color, javacv

Есть фото с маркером задача определить количество маркера на руке (У меня в пикселях).
Я написал программу который берет каждый пиксел и сканирует на синий или оттенок синего 2 фото результат обработки фото этой прогой.
[image: На руке есть маркер который отсвечивает УФ]

```
static boolean isBlue(int rgb){
    Color color = new Color(rgb);
    float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), null);
    // [0] is hue, [1] saturation and [2] value/brightnes

    if(hsb[0] > minHue && hsb[0] < maxHue && hsb[1] > minS && hsb[2] > minB)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

[image: После обработки]
Вопрос как можно улучшить программу?
Были идеи использовать JavaCV И OpenCV определить контур руки но попытки установки и разобраться с документацией закончились головной болю.

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать поиск объекта по цвету. Для этого используется функция opencv inRange и цветовая модель HSV. Такое недавно делал (питон): https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/opencv__Color_Detection_Tool

Comment: У вас проблема типичная для хромакея, думаю, что можно покопать в сторону алгоритмов в той степи. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы рассказали больше о том, как может располагаться маркер на руке (всегда ли это один кластер на ладони или могут быть измазаны пальцы? Как может быть расположено пятно, есть ли особенности по форме?) и в каких условиях будет происходить съемка (есть ли возможность добавить контрастный фон, исключить засветку одеждой).

Comment: @free_ze Маркер на руке может быть размазан, рука может быть покрыта маркером полностью, исключить засветку одеждой можно будет не всегда ну и в добавок освещение разное

Comment: Освещение можно нивелировать тем, что маркер скорее всего будет самой контрастной областью относительно фона. Но из-за одежды как минимум нужно определять нижний край ладони.

Comment: Остается еще пара плохих кейсов: фон, котрастный настолько, насколько и маркер, который "сливается" с фоном через край ладони и маркер, "вытекающий" за нижний край ладони (считать его или нет?).

Comment: @free_ze насчет фона могу сказать что камера будет в подвешенном состоянии и в большинство случаи фон это пол

Comment: JavaCV (обертка OpenCV), подключается классификатор и область руки определяется в 3 строчки

Comment: @DaysLikeThis если не трудно можно подробнее об этих 3 строчках

Comment: @Fedi Подключаем классификатор CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier("data\\haarcascade<имя>.xml"); Инициализируем указатель (привет с++ враппер)  RectVector rect = new RectVector(); Затем запускаем поиск областей на изображении  cascade.detectMultiScale(mat, rect); где mat - изображение, которое можно считать с помощью статической функции Mat mat = imread(filePath);

Comment: @Fedi JavaCV с помощью 1 зависимости мавена ставится - groupId: org.bytedeco artifactId: javacv-platform version: 1.4

Comment: @Fedi еще бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону DLIB (c++), там уже используются нейронные сети и точность обнаружения просто запредельная, если сравнивать с OpenCV